# How to get a node element attrbutes' values with Xpath using XPathEvaluate method in C#?

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

Consider the following XML body;

```
    <whitelist
              whitelist_entry_nb="4"
              whitelist_size="4000">
              <locations>
                <location
                  path="kate-api.gateway.zigbee-network.components.{component}.whitelist.{whitelist-entry}">
                  <var-fields>
                    <var-field
                      key="component"
                      value="F9BA2F5E2E1EBE1358F70691990F0918" />
                    <var-field
                      key="whitelist-entry"
                      value="8.042620EA5A3380" />
                  </var-fields>
                </location>
            <location
              path="kate-api.gateway.zigbee-network.components.{component}.whitelist.{whitelist-entry}">
              <var-fields>
                <var-field
                  key="component"
                  value="F9BA2F5E2E1EBE1358F70691990F0918" />
                <var-field
                  key="whitelist-entry"
                  value="8.043D147AA44A80" />
              </var-fields>
            </location>
</whitelist>
```

Xpath is:

```
/whitelist/locations/location/var-fields/var-field[@key="whitelist-entry" and @value="8.0440147AA44A80"]
```

Xpath Result must be as following:

```
Element='<var-field key="whitelist-entry" value="8.0440147AA44A80"/>'
```

What I want to do is passing this xpath into XPathEvaluate method and reach attribute values inside of XPath result Element which are "whitelist" and "8.0440147AA44A80". I want to check if those values exist or not in xml.

I'm trying to pass this xpath into XpathEvaluate method as following:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(response.Body));
var result = doc.XPathEvaluate(matchString[i].xpath);
```

*matchString comes from Json file

XPathEvaluate method returns a bool, string or IENumerable;
Which I can control the bool result here as following:

```
if(result is bool){
    resultBool = (bool) result;
    if(resultBool)
    {
        Report.Success("Content " + matchString[i].xpath + "is in reponse");
    }
    else
    {
        Report.Failure("Content " + matchString[i].xpath + "is not in reponse");
    }
}
```

I expect the output to be   Element=''.
I'll be able to get attribute values from here with using SelectNode method and etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var match = new Regex("^(.*)\\[@key=\"(.*?)\".*@value=\"(.*?)\"]").Match(matchString[i].xpath);

try
{
    string evaluator = match.Groups[1].Value;    // /whitelist/locations/location/var-fields/var-field
    string target_key = match.Groups[2].Value;   // whitelist-entry
    string target_value = match.Groups[3].Value; // 8.0440147AA44A80

    var doc = XDocument.Parse(System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(response.Body));
    var fields = (IEnumerable)doc.XPathEvaluate(evaluator);
    var values = fields.Cast<XElement>()
                           .Select(x => new {
                               key = x.Attribute("key").Value,
                               value = x.Attribute("value").Value
                           }).ToList();

    bool found = false;

    foreach (var val in values)
    {
        if (val.key == target_key && val.value == target_value)
        {
            found = true;
        }
    }

    if(found)
    {
        Report.Success("Content " + matchString[i].xpath + "is in reponse");
    }
    else
    {
        Report.Failure("Content " + matchString[i].xpath + "is not in reponse");
    }
}
catch
{
    //Invalid xPath format
}
```

Comment: The problem is I can't use a code line like this;                                                             
var fields = (IEnumerable)doc.XPathEvaluate("/whitelist/locations/location/var-fields/var-field");                                                                                                                             I need to get the xpath variable from Json file as a whole. I can't use typed xpath or I can't split attribute values as parameters. Basically I can not split the xpath, xpath is like a constant.

Comment: @rpcalisir so if you're already getting the path to evaluate from another source, and if I understood it correctly it looks like `/whitelist/locations/location/var-fields/var-field[@key="whitelist-entry" and @value="8.0440147AA44A80"]`, can't you trim the `[ ]` part?

Comment: Yeah you have understood correctly. I'm getting the xpath from another source, do you mean I can trim the [] part in program?

Comment: assuming `matchString[i].xpath` contains the value I stated above,  `matchString[i].xpath.Substring(0, matchString[i].xpath.IndexOf("["));` will return `/whitelist/locations/location/var-fields/var-field`, which would be a valid XPathEvaluate input. If the formatting above doesn't work for all scenarios, please post more samples and I could share a solution using Regex parsing

Comment: Yeah that will work I guess but I need to try. Could you tell me how to reach those key and value variables also please? Because I couldn't reach those values.

Comment: @rpcalisir have you tried the code I posted in my answer? I edited the post according to what we just discussed, are the keys and values you need not present in the `values` list?

Comment: Yeah I've tried, I'm trying to reach the key and value with values.key and values.value but they are not presented in the list.

Comment: @rpcalisir well I'm afraid I can't help you further then, it works for me using the samples you provided

Comment: whitelist_value comes as an output as following: System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereListIterator`1[<>f__AnonymousType0`2[System.String,System.String]]

Comment: @rpcalisir it's in `IEnumerable<a>` format, where `a` is an anonymous class I created in runtime which consists of two fields: `key` and `value`. Convert it to a list `var whitelist_values = values.Where(x => x.key == "whitelist-entry").ToList();` or loop it using a `foreach` to visualize it's values

Comment: Works like a charm!! Can you do me a last favor please?                                              I want to use a forech loop like foreach(var whitelist_value in whitelist_values), check if whitelist_value.key matches with @key="whitelist-entry" and whitelist_value.value matches with @value="8.0440147AA44A80" which comes from Json as 'matchString':[{'xpath':'/whitelist/locations/location/var-fields/var-field[@key="whitelist-entry" and @value="8.0440147AA44A80"]','value':''}]